# How to use regexp for splitting string with complex delimiter in Matlab?

Tags: regex, string, matlab, delimiter

I have a string like this:

```
"%","W/m²","mm","Deg C","%","W/m²","MJ/m²","","uSec","","uSec","","uSec"
```

I want to split this, based on a complex delimiter: each item is bounded by hyphens (left and right) and separated by comma.

Remarks:

- characters like percent or power of 2 are included and should be read in. Here in my example I have 13 items listed (3 blank).
- Empy fields (items), should be also included (not discarded) and replaced by the strin 'unitless'
- Items can also contain white spaces ("Deg C")

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Isn't each item bounded by double quotes? Not hyphens? Do you have to use regexp? There is a simpler approach without using one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to achieve this, but regexp should do it. I prefer regexp('split') over strsplit for speed and compatibility reason. The latter is relatively new.

```
str = '"%","W/m²","mm","Deg C","%","W/m²","MJ/m²","","uSec","","uSec","","uSec"';
units = regexp(str, ',', 'split'); % split by comma
units = regexp(units, '(?<=").*(?=")', 'match', 'once'); % get content between quotes
units(cellfun(@isempty, units)) = {'unitless'}; % set empty to unitless
```